# Jupyter-Notebooks stuck at "Kernel starting,please wait" (R Kernel)

Tags: r, kernel, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel, jupyter-kernel

I'm new to Jupyter Notebooks and whenever I try to create a new notebook i'm unable to run any code because the R Kernel doesn't start. 
The window shows a message that reads "Kernel starting, please wait" and then changes to "Reconeccting".

So far i've tried with Chrome , Mozilla and Edge but none works i ran jupyter kernelspec list on the anaconda prompt and i can see i have the ir kernel installed.

Thanks in advance!